# Can I edit the UINavigationItem's title from within the app?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

So I want the ability to change the title of the UINavigationItem from within the app. To be more specific, I want to be able to tap the title on the navigation bar and have it go into edit mode; where I can type in a new title. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Eventually this is possible, but I'm sure, that this isn't the way Apple want's you to use the UINavigationItem. Instead you could add an edit button, and then in a new view you could allow to rename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite possible and not very hard in fact. Here are the simple steps:

- Navigation item allows for custom views in its title
- Add a view with a label similar to that of the native navigation item
- Add a transparent button (custom button) on top of the label
- Add a hidden text field on top of the button
- When the button is pressed, hide the label and show the text field - focus on the text field (becomeFirstResponder)
- You are in editing mode: now track for "Return" key being pressed, and once that happens set your label text to what has been entered, resign first responder from the text field and hide it, then show the label

If you adjust all the properties of the UI components it will look like your navigation item supports inline editing!